# Python TKinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im making an application about e-learning. On this particular page i want to be able to make buttons for the user to choose the difficulty level from easy, moderate and hard. After the button is pressed, the user will proceed to the next page either EasyLevel, ModerateLevel or HardLevel. How to fix my codes?

```
import Tkinter
   LevelBox = Tkinter.Tk()
   LevelBox.geometry("320x260")
   LevelBox.title("Diffuculty")
   LevelBox.withdraw()

   def Easy() :
    LevelBox.withdraw()
    easybox.deiconify()
    return

   def Moderate() :
    LevelBox.withdraw()
    moderatebox.deiconify()
    return

   def Hard() :
    LevelBox.withdraw()
    hardbox.deiconify()
    return

   b1 = Tkinter.Button (LevelBox, text="Easy",         command=Easy,height=1,width=7).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="e",pady=5,padx=5)
   b1 = Tkinter.Button (LevelBox, text="Moderate", command=Moderate,height=1,width=7).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky="w",pady=5,padx=5)
   b1 = Tkinter.Button (LevelBox, text="Hard", command=Hard,height=1,width=7).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="e",pady=5,padx=5)

   easybox = Tkinter.Toplevel()
   easybox.geometry("320x260")
   easybox.title("Easy Questions")
   easybox.withdraw()

   moderatebox = Tkinter.Toplevel()
   moderatebox.geometry("320x260")
   moderatebox.title("Moderate Questions")
   moderatebox.withdraw()

   hardbox = Tkinter.Toplevel()
   hardbox.geometry("320x260")
   hardbox.title("Hard Questions")
   hardbox.withdraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need follow oops concept in your code , just make a class and then in its initialization , write your first UI code then on button click you can open anther window and close last one.

like this code is written :-

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False, padx=100, pady=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
    root.geometry('300x200')
    root.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: __tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-toolwindow": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type_

Comment: I m using python 2.7.11 ,may it happen because of version.So i have to import Tkinter in python 3.5 , it should be like this **import tkinter as tk** .. what version of python you are using ?

Comment: I tried it in Python2.7.6 and Python3.4.3 and got the same error in both.