# Is there a way of changing '.mainloop()' in tkinter, python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a small project with some 'instructions' and at the end of the instructions I asked the user if they wanted a window with the instructions in it while the program was running. If the answer was yes, the tkinter code would run and because of '.mainloop()' I couldnt return to the menu. I could only get back when I closed the window.

```
def open_instructions_window():

    def close():
        w.destroy()

    w = tkinter.Tk()
    w.geometry("550x500")

    w.title("Instructions")
    w.configure(background = "black")

    label_1 = Label(w, text = "Instructions", font = "none 17 bold underline",bg = "black", fg = "brown")
    label_1.grid(row = 1, sticky = W)

    exit_button = Button(w, text = "CLOSE", bg = "brown" ,fg = "white",relief=SUNKEN, command = close)
    exit_button.grid(row = 20, column = 1, sticky = E)

    w.mainloop()# Because of this I couldn't get back to the menu
    menu()
```

Is there any other way of putting this so that when it is ran, the window will open and stay open and 'menu()' will be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another window containing your instructions by using Toplevel. The user can open the window with a button click and close it without affecting the main window. Check out the example from Jagandeep Singh: [Toplevel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389566/python-tkinter-gui/35389944#35389944)